# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Geliebte und Freundin

Tags: word-usage, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Geliebte und Freundin? Was bedeutet Geliebte, wenn die beiden Leute noch ledig sind?

Comment: Beachte, dass es mittlerweile eine Stack-Exchange-Seite [interpersonal.se] (auf Englisch) gibt, auf der Deine Fragen, die nicht die deutsche Sprache betreffen, beantwortet werden können. Diese beachte deren Richtlinien, bevor Du dort fragst.

Answer (score 5):

"Geliebte" kann man auch umgangssprachlich beziehungsweise "spaßig" für seine Freundin/Frau benutzen.

Grundsätzlich gilt aber:
Eine "Freundin" würde eher eine feste Beziehung als Paar implizieren - wobei das ja heutzutage auch sehr locker gesehen wird.

Die "Geliebte" wird im normalen Sprachgebrauch als die Frau gesehen, mit der der Mann (seiner Frau) fremdgeht.

Wäre locker lässig ohne großes nachdenken meine Meinung als "native german".

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Freundschaft

Ein Freund oder eine Freundin ist eine Person, mit der man gerne Zeit verbringt, der man seine Sorgen und Nöte mitteilt, mit der man freudige Momente verbringen will, und der man Geheimnisse anvertraut. Die Art der Beziehung, die man zu so einer Person pflegt, nennt man *Freundschaft*.

Freundschaften knüpfen Menschen in jedem Alter, von frühester Kindheit an, und im Normalfall mit mehreren Personen.

Auffallend bei Freundschaften ist, dass sie überwiegend (aber keineswegs ausschließlich) zwischen gleichgeschlechtlichen Menschen geschlossen werden. Männer haben meist mehr männliche Freunde als weibliche, bei Frauen ist es umgekehrt. Das lässt sich bereits im Kindesalter beobachten, und setzt sich bis ins hohe Greisenalter fort.

> Karl steht zusammen mit drei anderen Männern an einer Theke, als ein weiterer Mann ins Lokal kommt. Karl begrüßt den Neuankömmling und stellt ihm die anderen Personen vor:
>   *»... und das sind meine **Freunde**: Heinz, Willi und Kurt.«*
>
> Die vierjährige Lisa erzählt vom Kindergarten:
>   *»Die Laura ist meine **Freundin**. Und die Aisha ist auch meine **Freundin**. Und die Anna ist auch meine **Freundin**. Nur die Bianca nicht, die nimmt mir immer meine Puppe weg«*

Ein wesentliches Kennzeichen dieser Art von Beziehung ist das völlige Fehlen von romantischen und sexuellen Bestandteilen.

### 2. Paare

Langjährige Freundschaften zwischen zwei heterosexuellen Erwachsenen verschiedenen Geschlechts, oder zwischen homosexuellen Erwachsenen desselben Geschlechts, die der obigen Beschreibung entsprechen, gibt es zwar, aber die besondere emotionale Nähe einer Freundschaft bringt es in der genannten Konstellation fast immer mit sich, dass sich die beiden Menschen ineinander verlieben, und sich in der Gesellschaft so verhalten, dass man sie als ein Paar wahrnehmen kann.

Damit verbunden sind zärtliche Berührungen, Umarmungen und Küsse, die man auch in der Öffentlichkeit austauscht, wenn der gesellschaftliche Kontext solche Aktionen duldet. Auch sexuelle Aktivitäten, die dann natürlich üblicherweise in intimer Zweisamkeit stattfinden, finden bei bei den meisten dieser Paare statt.

In der englischen Sprache wird dieser Übergang dadurch zum Ausdruck gebracht, dass man anstelle von einem geschlechtsneutralen *»friend«* nun von *»boyfriend«* und *»girlfriend«* spricht. Das Deutsche kennt diese Unterscheidung nicht. Für alle drei englischen Vokabel existiert dieselbe deutsche Übersetzung, die jedoch auch in Fall des englischen geschlechtsneutralen *»friend«* nach Geschlechtern trennt: *Freund* oder *Freundin*. (Beispiele dazu habe ich weiter oben angeführt.)

In dem hier beschrieben Zusammenhang wird *Freundin* wie folgt verwendet:

> Gerd nähert sich seinen Freunden und hält währenddessen Händchen mit seiner Begleiterin. Noch bevor die beiden in Hörweite sind, sagt einer der Freunde zu den anderen:
>   *»Schaut mal, der Gerd hat eine neue **Freundin.**«*

Die Beziehung, die solche Paare miteinander pflegen, wird meist aber nicht *»Freundschaft«* genannt, weil *»Freundschaft«* fast immer als eine Beziehung aufgefasst wird, die frei von romantischen und erotischen Komponenten ist. Man spricht eher von einer *Liebesbeziehung* oder *Partnerschaft*. Einen einzelnen, allgemein anerkannten Begriff für diese Art der Beziehung gibt es nur in einzelnen Regionen oder sozialen Gruppen. Über den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum hinweg ist die Bezeichnung aber uneinheitlich. Daher sind auch eher vage Formulierungen üblich, wie zum Beispiel:

> Gerd und Irene *sind zusammen.*
>   Gerd und Irene *gehen miteinander.*

Solche Beziehungen führen in vielen Fällen zur Eheschließung (oder zu einer eingetragenen Partnerschaft bei homosexuellen Paaren in Ländern in denen es  nicht allen Menschen erlaubt ist, eine Ehe zu schließen). Die Beziehung heißt dann *Ehe* (oder *eingetragene Partnerschaft*), und die Bezeichnungen *Freund* und *Freundin* werden dann nicht mehr verwendet. Man spricht in diesem Fall dann von *Ehemann* und *Ehefrau*, oder einfach nur von *Mann* und *Frau*.

### 3. Geliebte

Das ist, von der eigentlichen Bedeutung des Wortes her, zunächst ganz einfach nur eine weibliche Person, die man liebt. Gerd, aus dem Beispiel in Punkt 2, könnte demnach seine Begleiterin seinen Freunden also eigentlich mit folgenden Worten vorstellen:

> Das ist Irene, meine Geliebte.

Das ist allerdings nicht üblich. Stattdessen wird Gerd eher sagen:

> Das ist Irene, meine Freundin.

Unter einer Geliebten versteht man nämlich eher eine weibliche Person, zu der man eine romantische oder sexuelle Beziehung unterhält, während man gleichzeitig eine Ehe mit einer anderen Person führt. (An die Stelle einer tatsächlich offiziell geschlossenen Ehe kann aber auch eine langjährige Partnerschaft treten, die zwar nicht auf dem Standesamt besiegelt wurde, sonst aber in der Art des Zusammenlebens einer Ehe gleichkommt.) Entsprechend wird auch ein männlicher außerehelicher Partner als *Geliebter* bezeichnet.

In der Regel wird versucht, eine solche Beziehung zumindest vor dem Ehepartner geheim zu halten. Mit der Geliebten geht man daher in der Regel ins Bett, aber man geht mit ihr nicht Händchen haltend über den Dorfplatz.

Die Bezeichnungen *»Geliebte«* und *»Geliebter«* sind aber einseitig: Der Ehemann, der eine Beziehung zu einer anderen Frau pflegt, nennt diese außereheliche Partnerin seine *»Geliebte«*. Es ist aber nicht üblich, dass diese Frau ihren Partner, der mit einer anderen Frau verheiratet ist, ihren Geliebten nennt. Dafür gibt es, wie im Fall der romantisch-sexuellen Freundschaft, keinen allgemein üblichen Begriff.

Als Synonym für den männlichen Geliebten sind übrigens *»Liebhaber«* und *»Lover«* sehr verbreitet (sogar häufiger als *»Geliebter«*), während für die weibliche Geliebte kaum andere Begriffe verwendet werden.

Comment: Aber wenn die beiden Personen noch ledig sind, was bedeutet Geliebte?

Comment: Ich bin mir nichtmal sicher, ob es so etwas gibt...impliziert Geliebte nicht, dass der Mann vergeben ist und sich mit seiner "Geliebten" vergnügt?

Comment: @Han那: Wenn die beiden Personen ledig sind, und wenn man nur das Wort »Geliebte« hört, und sonst nichts über die Personen weiß, dann geht man davon aus, dass der Mann eine feste Beziehung zu einer anderen Frau hat, die einer Ehe gleich kommt.

Comment: Er hat keine Freundin und Ehrfrau, deswegen finde ich sehr selten.

Comment: @HanKim die Geliebte ist immer die inoffizielle Freundin, völlig egal ob sie nun die erste oder zweite Geige spielt. Diese "neudeutsche" Interpretation in der Antwort darunter ist merkwürdig, weil Freundin sowohl eine platonische, als ob auch eine sexuelle Beziehung bezeichnet (der Begriff Freundin oder Ehefrau kann/sollte beide Aspekte erfüllen). Bei Mädels, zu denen man keine platonische Beziehung hat, spricht man meist von einer Bekannten, guten Bekannten  (angehende platonische Beziehung) oder gar sehr guten Bekannten (stabile platonische Beziehung).

Comment: Ja. Ich verstehe. Aber ein Mann möchte die Eltern von Geliebte kennenlernen, ist das in Ordnung?

Answer (score 3):

In "modernem Deutsch": "Geliebte" ist "die Frau, mit der man Sex hat". (Außer man bezeichnet sie als "platonische Geliebte" und nimmt das damit explizit aus)

"Freundin" hat eine wesentlich größere Bandbreite: Von "kenne ich flüchtig" (Facebook-Freundin) bis zur Bedeutung von "Geliebte" ist alles im Begriff enthalten und könnte gemeint sein.

Der eheliche Status der beiden Betroffenen hat keinen Einfluß auf die Bedeutung des Begriffs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63229/discussion-on-answer-by-tofro-was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-geliebte-und-freu).